# Concatenate a string with an array for recursively copy file in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a concatenation problem between a string and an array
I want to copy all the files contained in the directories stored in the array, my command is in a loop (to recursively copy my files)

```
yes | cp -rf "./$WORK_DIR/${array[$i]}/"* $DEST_DIR
```

My array :

```
array=("My folder" "...")
```

I have in my array several folder names (they have spaces in their names) that I would like append to my $WORK_DIR to make it possible to copy the files for **cp**.
But I always have the following error

```
cp: impossible to evaluate './WORKDIR/my': No such files or folders
cp: impossible to evaluate 'folder/*': No such files or folders
```

Comment: What is `$i`? Is this inside a loop?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't detail that.

Comment: From example, it looks like ```$i``` is the iterator for the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=("My folder" "This is a test")

i=0
while [[ ${i} -lt ${#arr[@]} ]]; do
    echo ${arr[${i}]}
    cp -rfv ./source/"${arr[${i}]}"/* ./dest/.
    (( i++ ))
done

exit 0
```

I ran the script.  It gave me the following output:

```
My folder
'./source/My folder/blah-folder' -> './dest/./blah-folder'
'./source/My folder/foo-folder' -> './dest/./foo-folder'
This is a test
'./source/This is a test/blah-this' -> './dest/./blah-this'
'./source/This is a test/foo-this' -> './dest/./foo-this'
```

Not sure of the exact difference, but hopefully this will help.

Comment: It's strange, I suspect it's a bug in my virtual machine where I'm working on (I made changes that could have an impact on bash itself). I just tested your code, it works. And mine (on another VM) it's work, so I'm really sorry to bother you :'(